# HTML text field's label showing in three lines

Tags: html, css, label, textfield, htmltext

I have created a input text field and given a label to it using html but instead of showing label in one line I am facing problem that the label is showing in three lines.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  left: -193px;
  color: #999;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="verficationcode" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="verficationcode">Enter code here</label>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdPGT.png)

Comment: because you're giving it width 5px, removing it should work without setting nowrap

Answer (score 1):

Comment out or adjust the `width` property:

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 5px;*/
    top: 0px; 
    /*left: -193px;*/
    color: #999;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="verficationcode" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="verficationcode">Enter code here</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css,

```
label{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

but you can use placeholder instead of label like this

```
<input type="text" name="verficationcode" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter verification code here">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Position of html and using this css

```
label{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:0px; 
    padding-right:15px;
    color:#999;
    font-family:'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    z-index:1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```css
label{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:0px; 
    padding-right:15px;
    color:#999;
    font-family:'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    z-index:1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<label for="verficationcode">Enter code here</label>
<input type="text" name="verficationcode" required autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review below code.
Remove position, left, top property from CSS that is not needed here.

```css
label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    color:#999;
    font-family:'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    z-index:1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="verficationcode" required autocomplete="off">
<label for="verficationcode">Enter code here</label>
```

May be it will help you.
Thanks.